# Inserting contact to Samsung I9000 Galaxy S returns an exception

Tags: android

I have this code for inserting contacts tested on all HTC devices and it seems to be working fine until I tried it on a Samsung I9000 Galaxy S which gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException on this particular line of code

```
String strDisplayName = "First Name" + " " + "LastName";
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, strDisplayName);
Uri rawContactUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values); //java.lang.NullPointerException here
```

It seems like this URI doesn't exist or maybe samsung has a different way on inserting contacts. Has anyone experience this on samsung galaxy device? Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Actually the code that I have works. I upgraded the firmware to 2.2 from 2.1. I also tried what @Nic Strong suggested and it also works on the 2.2 platform. I guess this is a limitation on the 2.1 build for Samsung Galaxy I9000 S. Thank you for all your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting into RawContacts but this does not have a column DISPLAY_NAME column. This is part of the RawContacts.Data entity. 
Your insert should look like this:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
          new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

 int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
          .build());

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
          .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
          .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
          .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, strDisplayName)
          .build());

 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

This code won't run on all devices though as you should also specifiy and account to create the contact in. Where do you want to create the contact? A phone contact? A google contact? IIRC I think on Galaxy S to create a phone contact you should set the account type and name to blank (not null). That would change the first operation to:

```
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
          .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "")
          .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "")
          .build());
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, I tried your code and unfortunately I still get the java.lang.NullPointerException with or without the account type.

Comment: And account name? Can you post a stack trace.

Comment: Yes, I meant both account type and account name present or without it. I will try to post the stack trace on the Answers if this is okay or just here in the comments.

Comment: WARN/System.err(7660): java.lang.NullPointerException
WARN/System.err(7660):at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1224)
WARN/System.err(7660):at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
WARN/System.err(7660):at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
WARN/System.err(7660):at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:486)

Comment: WARN/System.err(7660):at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:104)
WARN/System.err(7660):at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:661)

Comment: sorry for the formatting, the exception occurs on the applyBatch() function. I just want to state that I have a valid context to invoke getContentResolver(). Hope this can help =)

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, you are able to "watch" your variables or you could test null variables.

Also, there's code missing: Where's the act (= activity?) coming from, that's probably the one which is NULL.

Comment: Hi I edited the variable to be context rather than act. But anyways there are no null variables as I have checked. I mentioned also that the code works on all htc devices I have tested except on the samsung. Thanks